# what tools can I use to build drill down graphs?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, dc.js

I want to build custom graphs that have interactive filters(drill down), very much like Kibana's dashboards(something like [this](http://demo.packetbeat.com/) one for example), where you can select a time period, in one graph and that time period is reflected to all other graphs, going deeper into the results.

Is there a tool to make it easier to develop this kind of interactivity (besides doing it by hand with d3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search, I've found http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/, which is exactly what I was looking for.